# Facebook PHP SDK limitations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a page on my site that pulls in analytics data from Facebook posts and pages, and have began with trying out the PHP SDK for Facebook.

The documentation seems to have improved in the last few months since the last time I used it, but as there is so much going on, I find it difficult to find the exact answer to my questions sometimes.

I want to get the analytics data for a number of posts and pages which are not necessarily related to each other... and also want to do this without logging in via Facebook. Is there some sort of simple API key I can use, which skips the logging in stage? I want a number of different peple to go to the site and see info from a number of different posts and pages.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be able to get limited data from public pages and posts without logging in. Data includes number of likes, public page information, comment and likes on posts etc.

For example, if I look at the following Page `https://graph.facebook.com/thetimberyard`, I can see various stats like:

- checkins
- talking_about_count
- were_here_count
- likes

However, you can get better insights if you ask the user to login with `read_insights` permission. This permission will give you access to full insights for pages you own. Extra insights include (but not limited to):

- Daily New Likes
- Daily Unlikes
- Daily Non/Logged-in Page Views
- Weekly Non/Logged-in Page Views
- Daily Internal Referrers
- Daily External Referrers
- Daily/Weekly/Monthly People Talking About This
- Daily/Weekly/Monthly Reach Demographics, etc.